# Tesseract OCR is inaccurate for images with letter spacing

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract OCR to extract a string of characters (not a valid word) from an image. The issue is that the characters in the image are spaced out, like in the picture below.
[image]
With default properties, this image is recognized as `5 O M E T E—E X fT`.

I tried to tinker with the page segmentation properties, but the closest I got is `"SOME TEXT.` with `--psm 8`. I'm wondering if there is a setting that will enable Tesseract to better deal with the spacing in between the letters, or if I need to train a custom model.

Answer (score 1):

1st way is resizing the image.

If you resize the image (0.15, 0.15)

[image]

With default properties you will get:

```
S O M E T E X T
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

bgr = cv2.imread("BdgJJ.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized = cv2.resize(gray, (0, 0), fx=.15, fy=.15)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized)
print(text)
```

2nd way is using [adaptive threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

If you apply adaptive threshold:

[image]

With psm mode 6, result will be:

```
S O M E T E X T
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

bgr = cv2.imread("BdgJJ.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 2)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config="--psm 6")
print(' '.join(ch for ch in text if ch.isalnum()).upper()[:-1])
```